# Me tira un error al inicializar una matriz en java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

//En esta linea de código me salta el error, Dice que es un erro de sitáxis.
int mat [] [] = {{1,2,3,}, {1,4,5,}, {1,4,9,} };

Comment: Revisa cómo se declaran los [arreglos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Tu problema no se puede reproducir. Esa sintaxis [es totalmente válida](https://ibb.co/JyWQ2pj).